# Scraping the data from website under the map by using python Selinium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a requirement to pull all the URLs from a webpage and data from the map if there is a map in the webpage.

I was able to get all the URLs from the webpage by using Python Selenium but not able to get the data under the map.

This is the sample URL. In Google, I searched for "tool rental" and got the following URL. In the following webpage there is a map, I was trying to get the data under the map.

URL:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=tool+rental&rlz=1C1GCEA_en&oq=tool+rental&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

Map:

[image]

Desired Output:

```
The Rental Center at The Home Depot
Northside Tool Rental
Northside Tool Rental
```

I tried different options(`find_eliment_by_xpath`, `find_eliment` etc.) to get the above data but nothing worked.

The following code I was using to get the URLs and data from maps.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Chaitu\Projects\Media Marketing\brightlocal\geckodriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=tool+rental&rlz=1C1GCEA_en&oq=tool+rental&aqs=chrome.0.0l6.1735j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8")
driver.save_screenshot('image.png')

element=driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
element_png = element.screenshot_as_png
with open("test2.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(element_png)


elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
for elem in elems:
    print str(elem.get_attribute("href"))
with open("url_list.txt",'w') as f:
    for elem in elems:
        if 'maps' in str(elem.get_attribute("href")) or ('google' not in str(elem.get_attribute("href")) and 'blogger' not in str(elem.get_attribute("href")) and 'youtube' not in str(elem.get_attribute("href")) and 'https' in str(elem.get_attribute("href"))):
            f.write(str(elem.get_attribute("href"))+"\n")
```

Comment: your code seems incomplete?

Comment: it seems you have forgot to put the whole code. Above code basically gets the screenshot only.

Comment: updated with full code. Not sure what happened i copied full code initially.

Comment: Where is your code where you tried to get the names of the businesses? All I see is you getting every `A` on the page (yikes?). If you look at the elements that contain the names, it's pretty straighforward. Post the relevant code so we can see why it's not working. You really should just post an [mcve]... you have posted your entire script which makes it harder to narrow down to the specific problem you are asking about.

Comment: Are you really intending to screenshot the entire `BODY` tag? I thought you just wanted the map? The map is an `IMG` with an ID so it's easy to locate also.

Comment: depending on what you are ultimately attempting to accomplish, you may want to consider using the google maps api instead.  then you won't have to worry about doing all of this browser interaction.